Does Hallow stop me from leaving if I am within the area when it is cast?
I'm playing as a fairy, and was looking through the list of spells that affect me, but not humanoids. I came across hallow, which lasts until dispelled. It says fey, among other things, can't enter, which could be an issue already if it's cast around a major quest area, as I now have to just sit there and wait, but if it's cast around me, then does that mean I can't leave until someone else dispells it? Like, do the walls preventing me from entering also prevent me from leaving, or are they one-way?

I could be reading into it a bit too much, but it seems like you're very worried about being a fey. I would suggest taking a look at this question for a 10,000 foot view, and then talk to the other players and DM about your concerns as well. These are good things to ask in session 0, and ask here if it could be a problem. Some of these things may never come up in this campaign (Not that your questions don't benefit the site, I'm sure someone out there is faced with this issue).

Also, related question that likely has the same answer: Does the Hallow spell remove an existing charm/fear/possession effect from creatures that are already in its area when the spell is cast?

@TheLittlePeace yeah, I've played with people in the past who seemed to just do whatever they found funny. One time they farted fire at my character on purpose, ALMOST PUTTING ME TO DEATH SAVES, when I was the cleric, so I want to prepare for everything since I don't know these people very well.

Hallow's first effect does nothing to listed creatures already in the area.
This is primarily explained in the Sage Advice Compendium. I'll be borrowing @Thomas Markov's answer from Does the Hallow spell remove an existing charm/fear/possession effect from creatures that are already in its area when the spell is cast?

Jeremy Crawford explained spells like this in this Sage Advice article:

Some spells and other game features create an area of effect that does something when a creature enters that area for the first time on a turn or when a creature starts its turn in that area. [...]
Reading the description of any of those spells, you might wonder whether a creature is considered to be entering the spell’s area of effect if the area is created on the creature’s space. [...] Our design intent for such spells is this: a creature enters the area of effect when the creature passes into it. Creating the area of effect on the creature or moving it onto the creature doesn’t count.

Because the spell description for Hallow specifies entering the area as the trigger, this official Sage Advice ruling tells us that creating the hallowed area on top of the afflicted creature does not cure them of charmed, frightened, or possessed; they must leave the area and re-enter.

The same logic applies to the creature's ability to enter the area. Creatures that are in an AoE such as this at the time it is cast are not affected until the trigger happens. In this case, the trigger is a listed creature trying to enter the Hallowed area. Since that trigger doesn't happen, nothing happens.

You might mention that Hallow's casting time is 24 hours, and all during that time the caster must maintain concentration or the spell fails.  If OP is worried about it being cast "around them" they should generally have time to get out or counter the casting before it takes effect, even for those effects which will impinge on them.
